# Errors: Expected declaration, Use of undeclared type 'Object', Use of undeclared type 'JSON'

Tags: json, swift, objectmapper

Started integrating the ObjectMapper in my iOS application to map the objects to entities. But getting errors

```
Errors: Expected declaration, Use of undeclared type 'Object', Use of undeclared type 'JSON'
```

[image]

Comment: You need to upgrade to Xcode 7.3.

Comment: @jtbandes can you please tell, what is reason, so I need to update Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7.3 is required if you are ObjectMapper 1.2.0 and up